# CakePhp Upload Validation

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I've been trying to get this to work for a bunch of hours, countless googling has not resulted in anything helpful.

I was wondering if there was a way to validate on the variables inside of a form fileinput. So like in a form "upload" I want to make sure that upload[name] is not empty. Could I do this at all with Cakephp's model validation?

Comment: Have you looked into using a cake file upload plugin? Meio upload is simple and good. Cakephp media plugin is apparently great but complex to get working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way in Cakephp to validate fileinput field.

You can do it by custom validation rules like below example

for view file

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->file('image');
    echo $this->Form->error('image');
?>
```

For model file

```
<?php
    public $validate = array(
        'image' => array(
            'rule' => array('chkImageExtension'),
            'message' => 'Please Upload Valid Image.'
        )
    );



    public function chkImageExtension($data) {
       $return = true; 

       if($data['image']['name'] != ''){
            $fileData   = pathinfo($data['image']['name']);
            $ext        = $fileData['extension'];
            $allowExtension = array('gif', 'jpeg', 'png', 'jpg');

            if(in_array($ext, $allowExtension)) {
                $return = true; 
            } else {
                $return = false;
            }   
        } else {
            $return = false; 
        }   

        return $return;
    }   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sunman Singh's answer is not true anymore.

```
static Validation::extension(mixed $check, array $extensions = array('gif', 'jpeg', 'png', 'jpg'))
```

> This rule checks for valid file extensions like `.jpg` or `.png`. Allow
>   multiple extensions by passing them in `array` form.

```
public $validate = array(
  'image' => array(
    'rule' => array(
          'extension',
           array('gif', 'jpeg', 'png', 'jpg')
      ),
      'message' => 'Please supply a valid image.'
  )
);
```

---

```
static Validation::fileSize($check, $operator = null, $size = null)
```

> This rule allows you to check filesizes. You can use `$operator` to
>   decide the type of comparison you want to use. All the operators
>   supported by `comparison()` are supported here as well. This method will
>   automatically handle array values from `$_FILES` by reading from the
>   `tmp_name` key if `$check` is an `array` and contains that key:

```
public $validate = array(
  'image' => array(
      'rule' => array('fileSize', '<=', '1MB'),
      'message' => 'Image must be less than 1MB'
  )
);
```

See the link below for references. Altough, I'd recommend writting your own function for more security but those can certainly save you some time

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation::extension